# Can't call paths to instances in application.html.erb - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, routes, view

I have instances of elements showing up on a sidebar, however, when I click the links to view the show page. it throws :

> NoMethodError in Items#show
>
> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

my view looks like this:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
      <%= link_to item.name, item %>
<% end %>
```

furthermore, when I use these links in the index.html.erb page they work.

Comment: Post the index method of your items_controller.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your @items var, it seems that it is nil, and calling nil.each... does not work